# '%s not in index' % objarr[mask]

Tags: python, pandas, scatter

I have the following code:

```
##Overall reported expertise men vs women

import sys, re
import numpy as np
import smtplib
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from random import randint
import csv
import pylab as pl
import math
import pandas as pd
from pandas.tools.plotting import scatter_matrix
import argparse

parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
parser.add_argument('-inVar', '--x', help = 'independent variable')

if len(sys.argv) == 1:
    parser.print_help()
    sys.exit(1)

args = parser.parse_args()

##Manipulating data so it can be graphed more easily
df1 = pd.read_csv('atc17-pcinfo.csv')
df1['Gender'] = df1['Gender'].replace(['M'], int(1))
df1['Gender'] = df1['Gender'].replace(['F'], int(2))
df1['Gender'] = df1['Gender'].convert_objects(convert_numeric = True)

x = df1['Gender']
y = df1['topic: Big data infrastructure']
print list(df1)

ax = df1.plot.scatter(x = x, y = y)
labels = [item.get_text() for item in ax.get_xticklabels()]
labels[1] = 'M'
labels[6] = 'F'
ax.set_xticklabels(labels)
#ax.set_title(y + ' vs. ' + x, fontsize=20)
plt.xlabel(x, fontsize=16)
plt.ylabel(y, fontsize=16)
plt.show()
```

I am trying to create a scatter plot using the data in df1. After I manipulate the data I have:

```
 Gender    topic: Big data infrastructure
    0     2     NaN
    1     1     -1
    2     1     -1
    3     1     -1
    4     2     1
    5     1     NaN
    6     1     NaN
    7     1     NaN
    8     1     -2
    9     1     1
    10    2     1
    11    1     NaN
    12    1     1
    13    1     -1
    14    1     1
    15    1     NaN
    16    1     NaN
    17    1     NaN
    18    1     -1
    19    1     -2
    20    2     1
    21    1     NaN
    22    1     NaN
    23    2     2
    24    1     -2
    25    2     2
    26    1     NaN
    27    1     2
    28    1     1
    29    1     NaN
    30    1     2
    31    1     NaN
    32    1     NaN
    33    2     2
    34    1     2
```

But I get this error:

```
     KeyError('%s not in index' % objarr[mask])
KeyError: '[ nan  -1.  -1.  -1.   1.  nan  nan  nan  -2.   1.   1.  nan   1.  -1.   1.\n  nan  nan  nan  -1.  -2.   1.  nan  nan   2.  -2.   2.  nan   2.   1.  nan\n   2.  nan  nan   2.   2.] not in index'
```

Can someone help me figure out why? I have looked at a few sources, but I did not see how my example pertained to theirs.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you have two problems:

The first one is that you are misusing `x` and `y` arguments of the `scatter` method. They should be passed column names of desired columns, not the actual values! So, it should be used like this:

```
ax = df1.plot.scatter(x = "Gender", y = "topic: Big data infrastructure")
```

Your second problem is that you haven't converted your 'Big Data' column into numeric values as you did with the 'Gender' one.

This should do the work:

```
df1['topic: Big data infrastructure'] = df1['topic: Big data infrastructure'].convert_objects(convert_numeric = True)
```

Since you will use column names a lot during DataFrame manipulation, I suggest you use shorter and easier names...

Below there is a working example:

```
# Read your copied df, saved as test.csv
df1 = pd.read_csv("test.csv",sep=",")

#rename df for easier work
df1.columns = ["Gender","Big_Data"]

# convert strings into floats/integers
df1 = df1.convert_objects(convert_numeric=True)

#Create figure by selecting desired columns as input x and y
ax = df1.plot.scatter(x = "Gender", y ="Big_Data")
fig = ax.get_figure()
fig.savefig('its_working.png')
```